# ¿Cómo agregar archivos jar locales a un proyecto Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencias

¿Cómo puedo agregar archivos [jar](/questions/tagged/jar) locales (que todavía no forman parte del repositorio de Maven) directamente en las fuentes de la biblioteca de mi proyecto?

Comment: en el archivo POM

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "locales"? ¿A poner los archivos .jar en tu repo maven local o a ponerlas en tu código digamos por eemplo en al carpeta de recursos?

Comment: Me refiero a poder importar un jar como dependencia al proyecto maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar el JAR desde la consola con mvn, como lo dice en la página oficial:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

mvn install:install-file -Dfile= 
-DgroupId= 
-DartifactId= 
-Dversion= 
-Dpackaging= 
-DgeneratePom=true

Where:  the path to the file to load 
 the group that the file should be registered under  the artifact name for the file 
 the version of the file  the packaging of the file e.g. jar