instalar Opencv en Mac OS chip m3 para java
estoy iniciando un proyecto con opencv pero al instalarlo con maven me da este error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java490 in java.library.path: /Users/stevefletesalfaro/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2458)

he intentado solucionarlo instalándolo desde homebrew, modificando su source para dejar buildJAVA=ON y tampoco, no hay forma de que me funcione

la información que se da es de una maquina virtual y con un conjunto de nombre falso de uso experimental.

¿Ya que mencionas que es un proyecto maven, podrías agregar tu pom.xml para ver como intentas poner opencv en las dependencias (y si hubiera un problema en ello)?

gracias por tu comentario, lo he arreglado , tuve que hacer una custom librarie

Te refieres a algo como esto:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106316/c%c3%b3mo-agregar-archivos-jar-locales-a-un-proyecto-maven?
